# How to use Javassist insert codes after super.xxx()

Tags: java, javassist

```
class A extends B{
public void a(){
    super.a();
    System.out.println("hello");
}
}
```

I wanna to use javassist to insert some codes after super.xxx , for example:

```
class A extends B{
public void a(){
    super.a();
    System.out.println("inject"); // javassist 
    System.out.println("hello");
}
}
```

if the origin codes not contains super.xxx , then just inject code use method.insertBefore .

My question is how to identify whether the method contains "super.xxx"
and How can I insert codes just like describe above  .

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it looks to be the end of the method where you want to insert the code so you can use `ClassPool` `insertAfter()` method to add lines at the end of the particular method.

Also you can user `insertAt()` method but it always insert before the line number specified.

Answer (score 0):

Javassist allows you to add code at a specific line number using the [`CtBehavior::insertAt`](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/CtBehavior.html#insertAt-int-boolean-java.lang.String-) method. Do however note that this requires you to compile your code [with the `-g` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) to include such line number information. Also note that this is generally not a good approach as changing your code will break your program or trigger your code at the wrong time.

Are you trying to execute code after calling the super method? If so, try instrumenting the super class `B` to contain the following code using `CtBehavior::insertAfter`:

```
if (this instanceof A) {
  // your code goes here.
}
```

This would have the same effect but is robust to line number changes.